# How developers keep reference to huge number of different entity prefabs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where I am generating infinite world like Minecraft's. The problem is that my game will have hundreds of types different animals and enemies, but I am not sure what is the usual approach of referencing those prefabs.

My solution at the moment is to have an animal factory class that can spawn animals. Looks something like this:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
    public static GameObject sheep = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Animal/Sheep");
    public static GameObject cow = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Animal/Cow");

    public static void SpawnSheep(float x, float y)
    {
        GameObject drop = Object.Instantiate(sheep, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    public static void SpawnCow(float x, float y)
    {
        GameObject drop = Object.Instantiate(cow, new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

But should I be caching reference to all prefabs or simply use `Resources.Load<GameObject>` once I need the reference?

I should also mention that animals get spawned fairly often.

So, what is the usual approach here? How do developers usually spawn animals if there are hundreds of different types in the game?

Comment: Just a side note, Minecraft is not infinite but only [practically infinite](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/The_Overworld#Limitations)

Comment: Yea of course, that is what I meant, but we can pretend it is infinite :)

Comment: You'll definitely want to look into "chunk loading", one of the core resource-management technologies used by Minecraft (and others)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should definitely cache the calls to Resources because unless Unity3D is doing some caching for you, it will need to repeatedly do a query for the resource. However the most pressing problem with your code isn't the performance. It's rather that you'll have to write a method for each animal, which is very pesky and also error prone if you later on make the spawning method more complex.

A better way is to reference your creatures via a string or numeric ID or enum in a dictionary. Leverage the power of dictionaries to victory!

### Using a string-based dictionary

One solution is to use a string-based dictionary like this:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
    // Dictionary to map a string to each animal object.
    private static Dictionary<string, GameObject> animalDictionary;

    // We'll build our dictionary in the static constructor.
    static AnimalFactory()
    {
        // We can load all the animals from that folder.
        var animals = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs/Animal");
        animalDictionary =
            new Dictionary<string, GameObject>(animals.Length);

        foreach (GameObject animal in animals)
        {
            animalDictionary.Add(animal.name, animal);
        }
    }

    public static void SpawnAnimal(string animalName, float x, float y)
    {
        if (animalDictionary.ContainsKey(animalName))
        {
            GameObject drop = Object.Instantiate(
                animalDictionary[animalName],
                new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Animal with " + animalName + "could not be " +
                "found and spawned.");
        }
    }
}
```

Pros:

- You need only one spawn method for the whole thing. Less error prone, less code.
- You need call Resources.Load only once for the whole thing. Better performance.
- Easily allows you to add more animals without needing to change code. Just drop them in the Animal folder.

Cons:

- Relies on the animal's name remaining constant. If you call `SpawnAnimal("Bear", 100.0f, 20.0f)` and later on you decide to change `Bear` to `GrizzlyBear` the method will stop working altogether because it won't find the entry in the dictionary. It will also fail if you misspell the name.
- You have to keep only animals in the Animal folder because Resources.LoadAll loads that entire directory.

### Using an enum-based dictionary

The second con is pretty acceptable. But the first con is very nasty! An enum-based dictionary can fix those two cons for us.

1. Create an `enum` that holds all of the names for your animals. This way if you use an `enum` instead of a `string` there's no chance of misspelling it and you can safely change an enum's name in the entire project you have. We'll call this enum `AnimalType`.
2. Create a Monobehavior class that we'll call `AnimalTypeHolder` with a single `AnimalType` public variable.
3. Add the `AnimalTypeHolder` component to every animal in the animal folder.
4. When you run the static constructor of `AnimalFactory` to build the dictionary you use `GetComponent<AnimalTypeHolder>()`. If the GameObject has an `AnimalTypeHolder` component we know for sure we're supposed to load it! That means we got rid of the second con! Putting a file that isn't supposed to be there in the Animal folder won't cause trouble! After we get the component we retrieve the `AnimalType` enum and store the enum and its respective GameObject into the dictionary. Since we're using enums instead of strings we got rid of the first con too!
5. Recode `SpawnAnimal` to use the `AnimalType` enum instead of a string.

The Enum:

```
public enum AnimalType
{
    Cow,
    Sheep,
    Bear
}
```

The Component that holds our enum and needs to be added and set to every animal GameObject in the Animal folder:

```
public class AnimalTypeHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimalType type;
}
```

Our modified `AnimalFactory`:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<AnimalType, GameObject> animalDictionary;

    static AnimalFactory()
    {
        var animals = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs/Animal");
        animalDictionary =
            new Dictionary<AnimalType, GameObject>(animals.Length);

        foreach (GameObject animal in animals)
        {
            var typeHolder = animal.GetComponent<AnimalTypeHolder>();
            if (typeHolder != null)
            {
                animalDictionary.Add(typeHolder.type, animal);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SpawnAnimal(AnimalType animalType, float x, float y)
    {
        if (animalDictionary.ContainsKey(animalType))
        {
            GameObject drop = Object.Instantiate(
                animalDictionary[animalType],
                new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Animal with " + animalType + "could not be " +
                "found and spawned.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now it takes slightly longer to set up your animals since you need to add the component but you've eliminated an entire class of errors by doing all of this! And adding new animals is still easy! Just:

1. Put the prefab in the Animals folder.
2. Add a new value to the `AnimalType` enum for this new animal.
3. Add the `AnimalTypeHolder` Component to the prefab.
4. Set the `AnimalType` in the `AnimalTypeHolder` component to the new enum value we made. Done!

Of course this is just a general idea on how to do this. If all of your animals already have something like an Animal component you could just put the whole functionality of the `AnimalTypeHolder` in that Animal component. I just want to communicate the concept. You'll know how to best implement it according to your own requirements.

---

### Increasing Performance - Object Pooling

Now to further address your worries regarding performance. There is one universal answer to improving the performance of instantiating GameObject's in Unity. **Object Pooling, Object Pooling, Object Pooling.**

Object Pooling is when you store GameObjects in advance and/or instead of destroying GameObjects you deactivate them and reset them and put them in storage for reuse. If you're going to Instantiate 200 Sheep, that can make the game lag. So you can Instantiate 200 Sheep beforehand when the level is loading, deactivate them before the game starts and then instead of Instantiating Sheep you just spawn the Sheep you've already Instantiated by simply moving them to the appropriate location and activating their GameObject. So the primary objective is to avoid using Instantiate as much as possible during the game or to avoid using it when the game is too busy using CPU for other things.

There are many assets and tutorials on the internet on how to best achieve Object Pooling that I'm sure you'll find useful. I suggest you start researching the topic.

But I'm still going to give you a solid example of how to use Object Pooling continuing off the previous example!

We'll just add a `preallocateCount` variable to our `AnimalTypeHolder` component that tells our `AnimalFactory` how many of these animals we want to instantiated in advance:

```
public class AnimalTypeHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimalType type;
    public int preallocateCount = 10;
}
```

Now for our new `AnimalFactory`:

```
public static class AnimalFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<AnimalType, GameObject> animalDictionary;
    private static Dictionary<AnimalType, List<GameObject>> animalPoolActive;
    private static Dictionary<AnimalType, List<GameObject>> animalPoolInActive;

    static AnimalFactory()
    {
        var animals = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("Prefabs/Animal");
        animalDictionary =
            new Dictionary<AnimalType, GameObject>(animals.Length);
        animalPoolActive =
            new Dictionary<AnimalType, List<GameObject>>();
        animalPoolInActive =
            new Dictionary<AnimalType, List<GameObject>>(animals.Length);

        foreach (GameObject animal in animals)
        {
            var typeHolder = animal.GetComponent<AnimalTypeHolder>();
            if (typeHolder != null)
            {
                animalDictionary.Add(typeHolder.type, animal);

                // Since there are no active animals in the beginning, we'll
                // create an empty list.
                animalPoolActive.Add(typeHolder.type,
                    new List<GameObject>());

                // Make a list to hold our inactive preallocated animals.
                var prellocAnimals
                    = new List<GameObject>(typeHolder.preallocateCount);

                for (int i = 0; i < typeHolder.preallocateCount; i++)
                {
                    var go = Object.Instantiate(animal);
                    go.SetActive(false);
                    prellocAnimals.Add(go);
                }

                animalPoolInActive.Add(typeHolder.type, prellocAnimals);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SpawnAnimal(AnimalType animalType, float x, float y)
    {
        if (animalDictionary.ContainsKey(animalType))
        {
            var inactives = animalPoolInActive[animalType];

            // Check if we have inactive animals of this type we can use.
            if (inactives.Count > 0)
            {
                // We'll just get the last GameObject in the pool.
                int last = inactives.Count - 1;
                GameObject drop = inactives[last];

                // We have to remove it from the inactive pool now that
                // we're using it!
                inactives.RemoveAt(last);

                // Now we have to add it to the active pool.
                var actives = animalPoolActive[animalType];
                actives.Add(drop);

                drop.SetActive(true);
                drop.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector3(x, y, 0f),
                    Quaternion.identity);
            }
            // If we don't have them preallocated, we'll have to instantiate
            // normally.
            else
            {
                GameObject drop = Object.Instantiate(
                    animalDictionary[animalType],
                    new Vector3(x, y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);

                animalPoolActive[animalType].Add(drop);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Animal with " + animalType + "could not be " +
                "found and spawned.");
        }
    }

    public static void UnspawnAnimal(GameObject animal)
    {
        var typeHolder = animal.GetComponent<AnimalTypeHolder>();

        if (typeHolder != null)
        {
            AnimalType type = typeHolder.type;

            var actives = animalPoolActive[type];
            var inactives = animalPoolInActive[type];

            // Check if we're not accidentally using unspawn more than once.
            if (inactives.Contains(animal))
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Trying to unspawn an animal that " +
                    "should already be unspawned!");
                return;
            }

            // First we check if it exists in the active pool.
            if (actives.Contains(animal))
            {
                // If it exists then we have to remove it now.
                actives.Remove(animal);
            }

            // We have to add it to the inactive pool for later use.
            inactives.Add(animal);

            // WARNING: In most situations in order to be able to reuse
            // a GameObject like this you need to reset it! For example if
            // your animals have HP then you probably despawned them when
            // they got to zero! You need to reset the HP back to the
            // starting default if you want to reuse the animal!!
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Attempting to use Unspawn Animal on a " +
                "GameObject that is either not an animal or doesn't have " +
                "an AnimalTypeHolder component!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Such an amazing, well-written and detailed answer. Thank you sir!